# Unable to Start the Name Node in hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I am running the hadoop in my local system but while running `./start-all.sh` command its running all functionality except Name Node while running it's getting connection refused and in log file prints below exception

```
java.io.ioexception : there appears to be a gap in the edit log, we expected txid 1, but got txid 291.
```

Can You please help me.

Comment: Do you have a stand by node ?

Answer (score 4):

Start namenode with recover flag enabled. Use the following command

```
./bin/hadoop namenode -recover
```

Answer (score 3):

The metadata in Hadoop NN consists of:

- `fsimage`: contains the complete state of the file system at a point in time
- `edit logs`: contains each file system change (file creation/deletion/modification) that was made after the most recent fsimage.

If you list all files inside your NN workspace directory, you'll see files include:

```
fsimage_0000000000000000000 (fsimage)
fsimage_0000000000000000000.md5
edits_0000000000000003414-0000000000000003451 (edit logs, there're many ones with different name)
seen_txid (a separated file contains last seen transaction id)
```

When NN starts, Hadoop will load fsimage and apply all edit logs, and meanwhile do a lot of consistency  checks, it'll abort if the check failed. Let's make it happen, I'll `rm edits_0000000000000000001-0000000000000000002` from many of my `edit logs` in my NN workspace, and then try to `sbin/start-dfs.sh`, I'll get error message in log like:

```
java.io.IOException: There appears to be a gap in the edit log.  We expected txid 1, but got txid 3.
```

So your error message indicates that your `edit logs` is inconsitent(may be corrupted or maybe some of them are missing). If you just want to play hadoop on your local and don't care its data, you could simply `hadoop namenode -format` to re-format it and start from beginning, otherwise you need to recovery your edit logs, from SNN or somewhere you backed up before.